# Remove invalid values . Backbone validate()

Tags: backbone.js

My example :

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   validate: function(attrs) {
        if (attrs.color  == 'muave') {
      return true; 
    }
  }

});

var me = new UserModel({ id: '123', silent: true });

me.on('invalid', function (model, error) {
  console.log('event invalid')
});



me.set('color', 'muave');
me.set('name', 'sasha');


if(!me.isValid()){
   me.clear()
}
```

I do not want to cleane all model   / only the properties that do not pass validation. 
It's possible ?

thank you very much

**UPD:
I do not know how good the way I did?**

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    validate_prop :['color','name'],
   validate: function(attrs) {

        if (attrs.color  == 'muave' || attrs.name == 'sasha') {
      return true;
      }
    },
    positiveValid: function(){

        for(var i = 0 ;i< this.validate_prop.length;i++){
             this.unset(this.validate_prop[i])
        }

    }



});

var me = new UserModel({ id: '123', silent: true });

me.on('invalid', function (model, error) {
  console.log('event invalid')
});

me.set('color', 'muave');
me.set('name', 'sasha');

if(!me.isValid()){
 me.positiveValid(); 

 me.isValid() //clear validationError: true

}
```

Maybe there is a more universal solution?
  thank you for your help .

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the default backbone API, I think you would have to implement your own function.

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly how I would go about it (note this is pseudo code I may have a mistake in there):

```
// An object of validation rules
validation: {
    color: {
        type: 'String',
        options: {
            notEqualTo: 'muave'
        }
    },
    name: {
        type: 'String',
        options: {
            notEqualTo: 'sasha'
        }
    },
},

initialize: function () {
    this.validation = validation || {};
},

validate: function (attrs) {
    this.invalidAttrs = {};

    // Loop through validation object, return the first invalid attribute.
    var invalid = _.find(this.validation, function (options, attr) {
        var type = attr.type || 'String';
        return this['validate' + attr.type](attr, options);
    }, this);

    // If there was an invalid attribute add it invalidAttrs.
    // Also trigger an event.. could be useful.
    if (invalid) {
        this.invalidAttrs[attr] = invalid;
        this.trigger('invalid:' + attr, invalid);
    }

    return invalid;
},

validateString: function (attr, options) {
    if (options.notEqualTo && this.get(attr) === options.notEqualTo) {
        return {
            'String cannot be equal to ' + options.notEqualTo
        };
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
if(!me.isValid()){
   _.each(me.invalidAttrs, function(reason, attr) {
        me.unset(attr);
   });
}
```

This would only find the error and then stop, you could quite easily change it to accumulate all errors. The fundamental thing is that you have a `validation` object you loop through which has validation rules for your model. When you say `type: 'Number'` in that object it will call `validateNumber(attr, options)` to determine if a number is valid. I would also recommend adding `required: true/false` for all types.

Here is a more involved and real world example of what I was talking about:

```
////////////////
// Validation //
////////////////

/**
 * Syntax for validation rules
 * @type {Object|Function}
 * validation: {
 *     <attributeNameA>: {
 *         required: false, // default, can be omitted
 *         type: 'string', // default, can be omitted
 *         options: {
 *             // type-specific validation rules, see validator
 *             // documentation
 *         }
 *     },
 *     <attributeNameB>: {
 *         validator: function (value, attrs) {
 *             // optional custom validator, validated first if present
 *         },
 *         required: true, // validated second if present
 *         type: 'date', // type validation is validated last
 *         options: {
 *             // type-specific validation rules
 *         }
 *     }
 * }
 */

/**
 * Validate model
 * @param  {Object} attrs   attributes
 * @param  {Object} options options
 * @return {Object|undefined}         returns validation error object
 *                                            or undefined if valid
 */
validate: function(attrs, options) {
    if (!this.validation) {
        return;
    }
    options = options || {};
    var invalidAttrs = {},
        validAttrs = {},
        isValid = true,
        isPartial,
        validation = _.result(this, 'validation');

    function checkValidity(rule, attr) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var error = rule && this.validateAttr(rule, attr, attrs[attr], options);
        if (error) {
            invalidAttrs[attr] = error;
            isValid = false;
        } else if(rule) {
            validAttrs[attr] = true;
        }
    }

    if (options.validateAttr) {
        var attr = options.validateAttr;
        checkValidity.call(this, validation[attr], attr);
        this.attrState = this.attrState || {};
        this.attrState[attr] = isValid;
        isPartial = _.difference(_.keys(validation), _.keys(this.attrState)).length > 0;
    } else {
        _.each(validation, checkValidity, this);
    }

    if (!options.silent) {
        isValid = options.validateAttr ? _.all(this.attrState) : isValid;
        this.triggerValidationEvents(isValid, validAttrs, invalidAttrs, isPartial);
    }

    // Note: successful validation needs to return undefined / falsy
    return isValid ? void 0 : invalidAttrs;
},

/**
 * Validate attribute with a given value
 * @param  {Object} rule    validation rule from validation object
 * @param  {String} attr    attribute name
 * @param  {Mixed} value   value
 * @param  {Object} options options
 * @return {Object|undefined}         returns validation error object
 *                                            or undefined if valid
 */
validateAttr: function(rule, attr, value, options) {
    var error;
    options = _.extend({}, options, rule.options);

    if (rule.required && (value == null || value === '')) {
        return {
            reasonCode: 'required'
        };
    }
    if (rule.type) {
        if (!this['validate' + rule.type]) {
            console.error('No validation found for type:', rule.type);
        }
        error = this['validate' + rule.type].call(this, value, options);
        if (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
    if (rule.validator) {
        return rule.validator.call(this, value, options);
    }
},

/**
 * Convenience method: check if a single attribute is valid
 * @param  {String}  attr attribute name to be validated
 * @return {Boolean}      true if valid
 */
isValidAttr: function(attr, value, options) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[attr] = value;
    var attrs = _.extend({}, this.attributes, obj);
    var error = this.validate(attrs, _.extend({}, options, {
        validateAttr: attr
    }));
    if (error) {
        this.validationError = this.validationError || {};
        this.validationError[attr] = error;
    } else if (this.validationError && attr in this.validationError) {
        delete this.validationError[attr];
    }
    return error === void 0;
},

/**
 * Triggers events for valid and invalid attributes after validation
 * @param {Boolean} isValid      was validation successful?
 * @param {Object}  validAttrs   attributes that were validated successfully.
 * @param {Object}  invalidAttrs attributes for which validation failed.
 * @param  {Boolean} isPartial    is it validating only a part of the model?
 */
triggerValidationEvents: function(isValid, validAttrs, invalidAttrs, isPartial) {
    if (!isPartial) {
        this.trigger('validated', isValid, this, invalidAttrs);
        this.trigger('validated:' + (isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'), this, invalidAttrs);
    }

    _.each(validAttrs, function(value, attr) {
        this.trigger('validated:' + attr, this, true);
    }, this);

    _.each(invalidAttrs, function(error, attr) {
        this.trigger('validated:' + attr, this, false, error);
    }, this);
}
```